# How to add a fourth vert to a triangle

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

As you can see in the picture below by extruding sides that were next to each other I have made weird crossing lines and shapes that messed the entire object up. Is there a way to add a 4th vert (corner) to the 3 already selected verts in order to fill the rectangular hole that I have.

I know I can subdivide the top edge and then move the vert on the edge but it will never be 100% in position and I can't align it to any vert or 3d cursor as you can see on the global orientation there, this is an angular side of a larger object.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from screenshot where edges should be crossing and where not, but there's likely non-manifold geometry which will be tedious to handle. It's easier to remodel that part. As to triangle for now no way to make it quad without deleting anything. Remove the edge going to the top, delete triangle and use F2 addon. But note that this won't be all problems solution

Comment: What's the F2 addon?

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/F2